# How can i use random color in colors array(not in single color) in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-test

If we need a random color for single color,
There are lot of methods
*like*

```
 color: Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)).withAlpha(0xff);
 color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
 color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
```

If i use the above color code in colors array it shows error,

but i want to use random color in colors array

**like**

```
              colors: <Color>[
                      randomColor,
                      randomColor,
                      randomColor,
                    ],
```

**My full code**

```
 Ink(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.blue,
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.green,
                    ],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
                ),
),
```

Please help someone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors you defined are not constant

```
 color: Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff)).withAlpha(0xff);
 color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
 color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
```

That's why you get the error in `LinearGradient` since you declared your `BoxDecoration` as constant.

```
Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception
```

To fix your issue just omit the `const` right before `BoxDecoration`.

```
Ink(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                randomColor,
                randomColor,
                randomColor,
              ],
            ),
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below

`final List<Color> colorCollection = <Color>[];`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  addColorToArray();
}



void addColorToArray() { //Here you can add color as your requirement and call it in initState
    colorCollection.add(Colors.green);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.black);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.green);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.black);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.green);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.black);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.green);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.black);
    colorCollection.add(Colors.green);
  }
```

Use it as below where you want to put random color

`color: colorCollection[random.nextInt(9)]`

```
Ink(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: colorCollection[random.nextInt(9)],
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80.0)),
                ),
),
```

Hope it's work for you

Comment: @AnandhKrishnan please check i have updated code

Comment: find out the issue bro , The issue is I need to remove const right before BoxDecoration

Comment: Great! Happy Coding